# Set Google map Api key programmatically in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there Any way to set the Google Map API key for V2 version programmatically  in android.

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: You get API key from google.

Comment: You have to set the API KEY within AndroidMenifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**, there is no way to set that programmatically right now.

Google said in it's documentation:

> To access the Google Maps servers with the Maps API V2, you have to add a
>   Maps API key to your application.... Add the key to your application
>   by adding an element to your application's **AndroidManifest.xml**
>   file.

Read it carefully, the notice is very very clear and you have no way to use other things rather than this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

For more clarification read:

- [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application)

Comment: If you think you got it, then accept the answer so that it may clear hesitation of others who are seeking answer of same thing.